# Pulling data to make a list

Tags: r, extract

I am still learning R but I am trying to create a list of books that are either Valente or main collection because I am trying to identify duplicates of book titles that are Valente and main collection. However, I am stuck on what to do further. I have cleaned the data, and I have programmed the column to hold a either Valente or main collection.

```
# Install packages
install.packages("readr")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("openxlsx")

# Load libraries
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(openxlsx)

# Read the text file
file_path <- XXXX
data <- readr::read_delim(file_path, delim = "|")

# Filter records with "Item_Type" equal to "CIRC_MANAGED" or "WITHDRAWN"
filtered_data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(`Item_Type` %in% c("CIRC_MANAGED", "WITHDRAWN"))

# Print the filtered data
cat("Filtered data:\n")
print(filtered_data)
View(filtered_data)

# Remove the filtered rows from the original data
clean_data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!(Item_Type %in% c("CIRC_MANAGED", "WITHDRAWN")))

# Print the cleaned data
cat("\nCleaned data:\n")
print(clean_data)
View(clean_data)

# Selects columns with the word Valente in the entry
valente_column <- clean_data %>% 
  filter(grepl("Valente", Item_Permanent_Shelving_Location)) %>%
  select(Item_Permanent_Shelving_Location)

# Filter records with "Item_Permanent_Shelving_Location" equal to "Main Collection" or "Has Valente in the entry"
MCV_data <- clean_data %>%
  dplyr::filter(`Item_Permanent_Shelving_Location` %in% c("Main Collection", valente_column))

# Print the Main Collection and Valente data
cat("\nMCV_data:\n")
print(MCV_data)
View(MCV_data)

# Remove the filtered rows from the original data
clean_MCV_data <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(`Item_Permanent_Shelving_Location` %in% c("Main Collection", valente_column)))

# Print the data that removed the filtered rows from the original data
cat("\nCleaned MCV data:\n")
print(clean_MCV_data)
View(clean_MCV_data)
```

I tried to to filter the data but it returned an error. The end result should be a list of book titles that are duplicates. There is two columns; one that has the list the title of book; and another that list the title of books as Valente and main collection. The goal is to retrieve a list of book titles from column 1 that are duplicates as in the title is in column 2. The books are considered duplicates if they has title then main collection, and title then valente.

EXAMPLE:

```
twinkle twinkle star | main collection
joe frazier | valente
anaconda | main collection
PCGR | main collection
twinkle twinkle star | valente
```

I want the code to pull the title twinkle twinkle star and create a excel file with all the list of books. I know how to create an excel file in R. However, I am stuck on how to extract the data.